# Webpack configuration intermittently working

Tags: vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

Yesterday I've struggled the whole day with my webpack configuration.

I've got a apache serving my php pages, with a proxy setup in webpack-dev-server config.
The problem is that when I load the page, the bundle is found, but apparently is like its not running at all!

After a change in the configuration, it did work, and I tought that the problem was solved, but today, after changing a single line, the problem occurred again!

After going back to the working configuration, nothing changed.

What the....? Please if anybody can give me any kind of suggestion, I'll appreciate that.

The application is made with Vue js, and in the browser console there's no message at all.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OK,

I'm sorry for the mistake, but for an unknown reason, my configuration file did go back to a previous version and I noticed the fact just now.

After repeating the change did Yesterday, the problem disappeared. I lost half of my day figuring out the problem that blocked the script execution, so I share the part of the code I had to remove in order to get a working configuration.

I'd like to know if anybody knows, why this piece of code is preventing the scripts in the bundle from running.

```
optimization: {
  runtimeChunk: 'single',
  splitChunks : {
    chunks: 'all'
  }
},
```

Thank you all.